# Base64 encoded web fonts

Tags: css, performance, browser, base64, webfonts

I'm dynamically adding a large (approx 170Kb) string of CSS into a <style> block. It is large because it contains a number of base64 encoded fonts in @font-family rules.

The time it takes to do this varies across browser - and is particularly slow on mobile. I'm interested in what might be happening for the bulk of that time. Is it the browser decoding the base64 strings that is slow, or is it parsing, applying and painting the fonts to the screen?

Does anyone have any insight into the kind of things the browser might be doing, or how I can go about profiling at that low level in Chrome or other browsers?

Comment: In Chrome you can use chrome://tracing/ but it isn't for the feint of heart.  It will tell you which threads (and functions) are spending time in a timeline during the operation you record